# Filtering dataframe columns with unsupported data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select columns by data type 'datetime.date'.

I am aware of the filtering method select_dtypes, but the problem is that the column containing dates have object dtype.

Suppose I have dataframes defined as below.

| num | ?? |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2013-04-26 |
| 1 | 2007-04-25 |
| 2 | 2020-09-21 |

I want to extract only date column, but there are multiple dataframes so I can't select such columns with fixed column name.
The only information I have is that the type of data is datetime.date, and the column's dtype is object.

```
df.applymap(type)['??']
0      <class 'datetime.date'>
1      <class 'datetime.date'>
2      <class 'datetime.date'>

df['??'].dtype
dtype('O')
```

Could you suggest a way to extract the date column?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of trying, I finally got the answer. Still, I will leave this post for those who are facing similar problems.

First, convert the dataframe into the boolean dataframe that indicates whether the data type in each cell match desired data type.

```
df_boolean_by_date = df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, datetime.date))
```

Then, you can filter out the date columns from the original dataframe.

```
filter = (df_boolean_by_date == True).any()
df_bool_sub = df_boolean_by_date.loc[:, filter]
```

From now, you can check the column names by `df_bool_sub.columns`.

If anyone have a better approach, please post yours. Thanks.